# I want to change my list with lists to a list with tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Right now I get this:

```
[[28, 27], [29, 27], [29, 28], [29, 29], [28, 29], [27, 29], [27, 28], [27, 27]]
```

I want this output:

```
[(28, 27), (29, 27), (29, 28), (29, 29), (28, 29), (27, 29), (27, 28), (27, 27)]
```

My code:

```
def load_seed_from_file(_file_name: str) -> tuple:
    """ Load population seed from file. Returns tuple: population (dict) and world_size (tuple). """

population = {}
file_name = Path(RESOURCES / str("seed_" + _file_name + ".json"))
print(file_name)
with open (file_name, "r") as json_file:
    loaded_json = json.load(json_file)
    for key, value in loaded_json.items():
        if key == "world_size":
            world_size = tuple(value)
            print(world_size)
        else:
            for i in value:
                if value[i] != None:
                    print(value[i]["neighbours"])
                else:
                    population.update({i: value[i]})
            print(population)
    return (population, world_size)
```

I'd like to change my list with lists to a list with tuples

Comment: So you're looking to get a list of tuples instead of lists?

Comment: May I ask why you want to convert the lists to tuples?

Comment: What does the code have to do with the question?

Comment: it´s need it to be a tuple later in my code, and yes i whant a list of tuples instead of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?tuple#tuple):

```
[tuple(x) for x in lst]
```

Comment: I downvoted because I didn't think it was useful, the op shouldn't need to have an unnecessary step to cast every list to a tuple when they appear to have full control on creating the output hence why they've asked the question.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre: Just because the code in an answer "works", doesn't automatically make it a good answer.

Comment: @Sayse @ martineau I got your point guys, and yeah maybe the answer could have been in the line: This is the answer to what you asked, but you should be trying this instead which is more efficient. However if the user is new, and may not even return, and there is no alternative answer explaining the correct appraoch, better he leaves with something than with no answer at all.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre - ["Because we are trying to build something that benefits the world at large, not just the one person having the problem."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315040/1324033)... answers shouldnt be targetted to just the single user

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for the link, I agree with the spirit of the linked Q&A. But the OP's question is closed: *This question needs details or clarity.* How can I help more than a single user in this case? How can I make the answer better? Seems like the downvote should go to the question, not the answer, which under the circumstances is OK. Meaning that the OP can build a list of lists, do whatever modifications of the **inner** lists, and **only** when all modifications of the lists are done, make it into a list of tuples.

Comment: @TimurShtatland - Closing the question *was* there to help the single user, the question was unanswerable in its current state since the code shown couldn't have created the output it was said to have done so it is then up to the OP to update their question. Feel free to post on [meta] to get a more rounded opinion but not all questions need an answer